# Joint entropy interpretation

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

Very straightforward question: how do we interpret joint entropy $H(X,Y)$? Higher values of joint entropy mean less uncertainty or higher uncertainty?

Comment: higher uncertainty, just as with the entropy of one random variable (it is, in the end, the entropy of the "joint random variable" $(X,Y)$)

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me, thanks! Differently for mutual information, for which higher values mean that knowing one variable provides more information on the other, right?

Comment: right ${{{{}}}}$